# Rename files in several subdirectories

Tags: bash, file-rename, mv

I want to rename a file present in several subdirectories using bash script.

my files are in folders:

./FolderA/ABCD/ABCD_Something.ctl

./FolderA/EFGH/EFGH_Something.ctl

./FolderA/WXYZ/WXYZ_Something.ctl

I want to rename all of the .ctl file with the same name (name.ctl).

I tried several command using mv or rename but didnt work.

Working from FolderA:

> find . -name '*.ctl' -exec rename *.ctl name.ctl '{}' \;

or

> for f in ./*/*.ctl; do mv "$f" "${f/*.ctl/name .ctl}"; done

or

> for f in $(find . -type f -name '*.ctl'); do mv $f $(echo "$f" | sed 's/*.ctl/name.ctl/'); done

Can you help me using bash?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with one line with:

```
find . -name *.ctl -exec sh -c 'mv "$1" `dirname "$1"`/name.ctl' x {} \;
```

The `x` just allows the filename to be positional character 1 rather than 0 which (in my opinion) wrong to use as a parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
find . -name '*.ctl' | while read f; do
    dn=$(dirname "${f}")
    # remove the echo after you sanity check the output
    echo mv "${f}" "${dn}/name.ctl"
done
```

`find` should get all the files you want, `dirname` will get just the directory name, and `mv` will perform the rename.  You can remove the quotes if you're sure that you'll never have spaces in the names.

Comment: This is the right answer.. but people will come whining about not iterating over the find's output. :P I guarantee it.

Comment: Thanks, I tried too, but strangely got message permission denied to 'create' regular file name.ctl?